# Loop through range and find value in another range

Tags: loops, while-loop, compare, concatenation

I would like to loop through a range and find matching values in another range on another sheet.
Once a match is found, I concatenate values in the column next to it.

My first solution works, but is highly ineffective and takes ages.

The two sets of data look like this:

Sheet1

Col A  -  Col B
1001  -  Harry and
1001  -  Hermine go
1001  -
1001  -  to the movies
1002  -  John Paul
1002  -  George
1002  -  and Ringo sing
1002  -

Sheet2

Col A
1001
1002

So the data in table 1 that match a value in table 2 (Column A) sit all in one place.

The result I want to get with my code is:

Col A  -  Col B
1001  -  Harry and Hermine go to the movies
1002 - John Paul George and Ringo sing

My 1st solution looks like this:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Compare As String
Dim str As String
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long

'Define Range for sheet 1
LastRow1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Define Range for Sheet 2
LastRow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop 1 to go through all values in Sheet 2
   For j = 1 To LastRow2
'Put value in variable
          Compare   = Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A" & j).Value
'Set Variable for texts to Empty
            str = ""
'Loop 2 to test if Value in Column A of Sheet 1 matches Compare variable
    For i = 1 To LastRow1
 'If Match is found AND Column B is not empty, Add contents of Column B to String variable                  
          If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = Compare And Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
                     str = str + Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value & " "
             End If
' Go to next row in Sheet1
        Next i   
'Add contents of string variable to matching row in Sheet2
      Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & j).Value = str
'Go to next value in Sheet 2 
   Next j
    
End Sub
```

So this works, but I have 19000 rows in Sheet 1 and 800 in Sheet 2 - and 5 Columns with text stings.

With this code, I compare 800 x 19000 rows. This is highly ineffective. Together with the If-Clause, concatenation and copying it takes 16 minutes - for 1 column.

But I know that the matches for each of the 800 values sit together in one place somewhere in the 19000 rows in the raw data table. So I really only need to go through 30 - 40 rows instead of 19000.

A better solution first identifies the row numbers of the first and last occurence of a match to the compare value in the raw data and loops only though these 30 - 40 rows instead of all 19000. The code takes just over 16 seconds - for all 5 columns.

It goes like this:

```
Sub Find_Examples_Click()
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet 'raw data
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet 'compare values
Dim POb As Range ' compare value to seach for
Dim Fadr As Range 'address of first match in raw data table
Dim Ladr As Range 'address of last match in raw data table

Dim Kopftext As Range 'range in raw data to loop through

Dim i As Range 'loop increment for search value table
Dim j As Long 'loop increment for raw data table
Dim k As String 'variable for  strings in raw data table
Dim LastRow1 As Long 'last row in raw data table
Dim LastRow2 As Long 'last row in raw data table
Dim Frow As Long 'row number of first address
Dim Lrow As Long 'row number of last address

Dim str As String 'variable that holds the concatenate of strings

Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Rohdaten")
Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Bearbeitet")

LastRow1 = Sht1.Cells(Worksheets("Rohdaten").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Sht2.Cells(Worksheets("Bearbeitet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'first loop: go through compare values and define range in raw data table
    j = 2
        With Worksheets("Rohdaten")
            For j = 2 To LastRow2
                Set POb = Sht2.Range("K" & j) 'load compare value into variable
                Set Fadr = .Range("K:K").Find(POb, , , , , xlNext) 'find address of first compare value occurence in raw data table
                Set Ladr = .Range("K:K").Find(POb, , , , , xlPrevious) 'find address of last compare value occurence in raw data table
                Frow = Fadr.Row 'get row number of first address
                Lrow = Ladr.Row ''get row number of last address

                Set Kopftext = .Range("C" & Frow & ":C" & Lrow) 'set range to loop through in raw data

'second loop: go through defined range
                For Each i In Kopftext
                 str = "" 'empty variable that will hold concatenate
                   k = i.Value 'load string value
                        If k <> "" Then 'only do something if in variable value is not ""
                           str = str + k & " " 'append value to existing string
                        End If
                    Next i
                Worksheets("Bearbeitet").Range("C" & j).Value = str 'copy string into the table with the compare value

   Next j
        End With

End Sub
```

So this is now way better than the 1st try, but I still think the code is rather clumsy and complicated. Would there
be an even better approach to do this to get the run time down even further? Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hashmap with Col A = Hashmap-key and Col B = Hashmap-content.
Loop Through Sheet1 and append the String in Col B to the Hashmap Content with the Key of Col A.
The Hashmap then contains ur result and you just need to print it out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).